# grammaticality of "unlike which"

Tags: grammaticality, formality, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

is it correct the use of "unlike which" in a sentence such as

> "..., therefore **a** is superficially identical to **b** (unlike
>   which, **a** can be paraphrased with ..."

meaning despite the similarity, a can be paraphrased with X, but b cannot.

Otherwise, can alternative wording would be just as concise?

Comment: No, it isn't and whether that's the constructed passage it seems to be, where's your own conclusion, let alone the research supporting it, please?

Broadly, "unlike which" would refer not to A or B directly but to the camparison between them.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "not to A or B directly but to the camparison between them". That seems an issue of ambiguity rather than grammaticality properly

Comment: No ambiguity, GJC: it’s just not correct the use of "unlike which" in a passage such as yours. 
The problem is not with English or grammar; just with logic. Far from concise, the wording is simply incomplete and confusing. That tends to conceal the fact there’s no place for “unlike”.
Reduce it to "a is identical to b, unlike which (anything)” and doesn't it become more clear, the fragment won’t support the interpretation “despite the similarity, a can be paraphrased with X, but b cannot”.